# Finding the minimum value after using zip

Tags: python, zip

Good day! I'm trying to learn about the zip() function. I combined two lists using zip.

```
a = [1,3,5,7]
b = [40,30,20,10]

c = list(zip(a,b))

print(c)
```

This is the output:

```
[(1, 40), (3, 30), (5, 20), (7, 10)]
```

I want to access the element of the zip function if the second column is minimum. For example, the minimum value for the 2nd column is 10. If I use the zip function and get 10, I'm expecting an answer of

```
(7,10)
```

I tried something like this:

```
for i,j in c:
    if c[i][j] == min([c[j]):
        print(c)
```

I end up with an error and don't know what to do. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `min(c, lambda x: x[1])`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
minimum = min(map(lambda elem: elem[1], c))

for elem in c:
    if elem[1] == minimum:
        print(elem)
```

Comment: @blhsing sorry, I misunderstood your statement. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `key` keyword of the build in `min` function to specify by which index you want the comparison

```
result = min(zip(a,b), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: The `list(..)` isnt needed just consume the `zip`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = [1,3,5,7]
b = [40,30,20,10]

c = zip(a,b)

print(c)

min(c, key = lambda t: t[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = [(1, 40), (3, 30), (5, 20), (7, 10)]

d1 = [x[1] for x in data]

print(data[d1.index(min(d1))])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index of the `min` element in a single iteration:

```
a = [1,3,5,7]
b = [40,30,20,10]

result = min((x for x in enumerate(zip(a,b))), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
print(f"Index of {result[1]} is {result[0]}.")
```

Output:

```
Index of (7, 10) is 3.
```

Unlike the accepted answer,  this only takes a single iteration instead of two.